# Finding $x$ such that $\lfloor x + 1/2 \rfloor = \lfloor x \rfloor$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find all real numbers $x$ satisfying:
>
> a. $\lfloor x + 1/2 \rfloor = \lfloor x \rfloor$.
>
> b. $\lfloor x + 1/2 \rfloor = \lceil x \rceil$.

Comment: Begin with a few examples, such as $x = 1$, $x=1.2$, $x=1.5$, $x=1.7$, etc.  Try to spot the pattern.

Comment: First, consider a positive $x.$ Write $x$ as $k + f$ where $k$ is an integer, and $f$ is a real number between $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 2):

This is homework, so you should really post what you have tried so far.

Nevertheless, I will give you the following hint: the floor function returns the integer part of any real number $x$, or in other word, it rounds every number down to the nearest integer.

So $\lfloor 5.9\rfloor = 5$ and $\lfloor 5.1\rfloor = 5$. If you added $1/2 = 0.5$ to $5.9$, would you still get $5$? What about if you added it to $5.1$?

**Edit to provide further hints:**

Let $5 \le x < 5.5$. Or, in other words, let $x \in [5,5.5)$. Does any value of $x$ in this set work for part (a)? Does *every* value of $x$ work?

Comment: I start with let x = n + s, 0 <= s < n, n is integer then floor (x +1/2) = floor (x) that is equal to floor (n + s + 1/2) = floor (n +s) then that is same as n + floor (s + 1/2) = n + floor (s) then i cancelled n. That's the point I dunoo what to do. How can I cancel floor (s) ??

Comment: You don't cancel floor. It seems like you're overcomplicating it. $\lfloor 5.1 + 0.5 \rfloor = 5 = \lfloor 5.1 \rfloor$, but $\lfloor 5.9 + 0.5 \rfloor = 6 \neq \lfloor 5.9 \rfloor$. Can you tell what the pattern is now?

Comment: Wait. From my solution. floor (s) = 0. so my working solution is only floor (s +1/2) = 0. so now, how can i solve for s?

Comment: You're not solving for $s$ in this problem. You asked to "find **all** real numbers satisfying...." So your solution will be a set of numbers, not a single value $x$. Do not try to "cancel out" floor operations or "solve for $x$." You are instead required to identify regions for which a pattern holds.

Comment: I edited my question together with my solution.

Comment: All you have done is reduced the general problem to a specific problem, where $x \in [0, 1/2)$. You still need to address the question asked in my most recent edit to my answer in order to solve your problem. You have done a lot of work for no true gain; please look at my answer and edit again, and try to describe the exact scenario and questions I pose -- they will lead you immediately to your answer. And then you will see how your current approach reduces the general problem to a specific case.

Comment: yes letter (a) works when let x∈[5,5.5) and when even we change the integral part.

Comment: Right! You have correctly determined that $x$ solves part (a) whenever $x \in [k, k+1/2)\ \forall k = 0,1,2,3,\ldots$. Now use the same reasoning for when $k$ is negative. Also, you can use the same reasoning for part (b). Remember, you're not trying to solve for specific values of $x$; you're trying to find the SET of values that hold true for any $x$ in that set.

Comment: So I dont need my solutions? ANyway, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Given a real number $x$, write $x=n+s$, where $n\in\mathbb Z$ and $0\leq s<1$. That is, we have $\lfloor x\rfloor=n$. Consider the following two situations:

1. $s\in[0,1/2)$;
2. $s\in[1/2,1)$.

What can you say about $\lfloor x+1/2\rfloor$ in these two separate situations?

Comment: Thats where I stopped? Am i right that floor (x +1/2) is not same as floor (x) + floor (1/2), x is real number?

Comment: In (a), I stopped in floor (s + 1/2) = 0. I dont know whats next.

Comment: @mth126 You are right: in general, the floor of $x+1/2$ is not the same as the floor of $x$ plus the floor of $1/2$ (which is simply 0). The problem with your decomposition $x=n+s$ is that you're not restricting $s$ enough. In my decomposition, I make sure that the floor of $x$ is exactly $n$.

Comment: @mth126 Hence, I separated $x$ into its integer part $n$ (which is *exactly* the floor of $x$) and its fractional part $s$. When I add $1/2$ to $x$, either the integer part of $x+1/2$ stays the same (when does this happen?) or it changes, in which case it increases the floor by exactly 1.

Comment: I edited my question. That's my solution. Which part is not clear in my solution?

Comment: @mth126 The only thing you proved in your solution is that, if the floor of $x$ is equalt to the floor of $x+1/2$, then the floor of $x$ is equalt to the floor of $x+1/2$. That is, you assumed what you want to prove.

Comment: Looking at your first comment again, case 1 works for (a) and case 2 works for (b)

Comment: @mth126 Yes, that is correct!

Comment: Thanks so much! Thanks for the patience.

Answer (score 0):

You're just fine up to "$\lfloor s+\frac{1}{2}\rfloor=0\quad$  I don't know what's next". Now you should look at the $s$ values that will keep $s+\frac{1}{2}$ from going above $1$, since then $\lfloor s+\frac{1}{2} \rfloor$ would no longer be $0$. You'll find that there is a limited range of possibilities for $s$, which when you add the integer part $n$ back in, will give you the form of the $x$ answers you need. Once you see this, part (b) should be easy.

Comment: No, the solution is not fine: the OP assumed what she was trying to prove!

Comment: So my solution have sense? Then I can conclude from that line that s = [0,1/2)

Comment: @MTurgeon. If you mean that the OP assumed that for integer $n$ and $s\in[0, 1)$ then $\lfloor n+s\rfloor=n$ then I would agree with you. However, my I read of the problem was that this result was already known to the OP and that the difficulty was that after using that result the answer was not yet clear.

Comment: @mth126. Yes. So your solutions will comprise all of the values you'd get by adding integers to those $s$ values.

Comment: @RickDecker I meant the line where the OP writes "floor($x$)=floor($x+1/2$)".

Comment: @MTurgeon. I see. A more felicitous wording (which I provided in my reading) would have been "$\lfloor x+1/2\rfloor = \lfloor x\rfloor$ if and only if..." and had continued in that vein until the conclusion "therefore, $x$ must have the form ...".

Comment: @RickDecker Oh, I see! Fair enough, that would have been a valid argument then!